# Datagramsocket only sends N-1th packet

Tags: java, android, datagram

In my Android App I'm using DatagramSockets to send messages to a server like this:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);

byte[] byteMessage = (" " + message + "\r\n##!!##").getBytes();

DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(byteMessage, byteMessage.length, address, port);

DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
try
{
        socket.send(packet);
}
finally
{
        socket.close();
}
```

But only every N-1th packet is sent.
Meaning if I send 1 packet, nothing is sent. If I send the second, the first one gets send. If I send the third, the second gets send etc etc.

---

**EDIT:**
So after the first comments I a) got rid of the useless throw-statement b) tried not closing the socket after sending. It doesn't help.
So as an example for clarification: The following code works perfectly and I receive the package server-side. But it's obviously not a pretty solution...

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);

byte[] byteMessage = (" " + message + "\r\n##!!##").getBytes();

DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(byteMessage, byteMessage.length, address, port);

DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

try
{
    socket.send(packet);
    String emptyMessage = " ";
    socket.send(new DatagramPacket(emptyMessage.getBytes(), emptyMessage.getBytes().length, address, port));
}
finally
{
    socket.close();
}
```

I'm just sending a second "empty" message afterwards. I first tried sending an empty byte array, but that does **not** work.

Comment: Keep the socket open. Don't create & destroy a new socket per message. And don't catch-and-throw. As shown here, it's comlletely pointless.

Comment: UDP makes no reliability guarantee, though your failure is intriguingly systematic.  You should include the multiple-packet sending code in your post.

Comment: @EJP thanks, I tried keeping the socket open. Sadly it didn't help. To keep it simpler for readers to follow, I didn't include it in my edit.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The packet sending is usually invoked by user interaction. I added a second-package-sending in my edit to keep the error hunt within one method.